# How to send event from Service to Activity with Otto event bus?

Tags: android, otto

Simple `BusProvider.getInstance().post()` bring exception not `main thread`.
How to send event from Service to Activity with Otto event bus?

Comment: By default Otto uses the MAIN thread (see thread enforcement: http://square.github.com/otto/). Are you trying to post FROM another thread? Include example code and your stack trace.

Comment: Another way of achieving this is to use `runOnUiThread`, provided there is access to an Activity. Not very clean but will do the job.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

To post from any thread (main or background) and receive on the main thread, try something like

```
public class MainThreadBus extends Bus {
  private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

  @Override
  public void post(final Object event) {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
      super.post(event);
    } else {
      mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          MainThreadBus.super.post(event);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Note: credit goes to Jake Wharton and "pommedeterresaute" at https://github.com/square/otto/issues/38 for the general approach.  I just implemented it with a wrapper class rather than a subclass.

Comment: Thanks. So as of now, does **Bus bus2 = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.MAIN);** resolve it?

Comment: For me `ThreadEnforcer.MAIN` did not resolve it, but the code provided here.

Comment: @platzhirsch from the doc: _If you are not concerned on which thread interaction is occurring, instantiate a bus instance with ThreadEnforcer.ANY_

Comment: @gdrc Thanks for catching up on this. After looking into the source code it became clear. I thought `ThreadEnforcer.ANY` is the default.

Comment: Why are you using a wrapper and a subclass? Very confusing.

Comment: Any idea if this would work on a `Wear` device using `WearableListenerService`?

Comment: why isn't this built into the library? Its a pretty common use case.

Comment: Not sure, but this code causes an out of memory error for me.

Comment: what is best approach to handle if `event` is null?

Answer (score 20):

To post from any thread (main or background) and receive on the main thread, use the following `MainThreadBus` instead of a vanilla `Bus`

```
public class MainThreadBus extends Bus {
     private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

     @Override public void post(final Object event) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            super.post(event);
        } else {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainThreadBus.super.post(event);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is based on Andy Dennie's answer.

There is no need to both extend and wrap a `Bus` object, do one or the other. In Dennie's answer, which is effectively a wrapper, the `Bus` base class is just being used like an interface, all the functionality is overwritten.

It would work even if you removed the `Bus` base class unless you happened to reference the `MainThreadBus` via a `Bus` reference.

Comment: My answer implemented an interface which was part of Otto at the time, but has since been removed (and someone edited my answer to make it extend rather than implement); that's why it looks odd now.  In my example I wanted to wrap another bus that was not limited to being used on the main thread only.

Answer (score 3):

Or simply do this if you're sure that you're posting from a Non-main thread:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mBus.post(new myEvent());
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY); is the clear solution to this problem. 
Its all you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Best implementation custom bus class for me

```
public class AndroidBus extends Bus {
    private final Handler mainThread = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void post(final Object event) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            super.post(event);
        } else {
            mainThread.post(() -> AndroidBus.super.post(event));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it simply:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bus.post(event);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Just create the `BasicBus` with `ThreadEnforcer.NONE` to post event from non-main threads. The mentioned `ThreadEnforcer.MAIN` is exactly the opposite (and the default), which accepts only posts from the main-thread.

Comment: It's unlikely that this is a usable answer. The OP says "... to Activity ...", which implies to me that the processing needs to be done on the UI or main thread.