# Communication between Service and Activity each hosted in different process using PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-service, android-pendingintent

I am starting a foreground service from a fragment which gets destroyed after call to `startService()`, which is a reason I can't use `ResultReceiver` or `Messanger`. So the option remains `PendingIntent`. How can I communicate between foreground service(hosted in different process) from any activity/fragment using PendingIntent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate issues:

1. How do you get data from the service process to the UI process?
2. How do you get the data from whatever you did for #1 to whatever portion of the UI needs that data?

There are any number of solutions for #1: `PendingIntent`, `ResultReceiver`, `Messenger`, AIDL-defined callback for a bound service connection, etc. #2 then mostly is a matter of using an event bus or something similar to alert all relevant Java objects about the new data.

So, for example, here is an off-the-cuff recipe for using a `PendingIntent` for this:

1. Implement a `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service` in your activity process, registered in the manifest, but with no `<intent-filter>`
2. As part of calling `startService()`, create a `PendingIntent` using its `getBroadcast()` or `getService()` factory method, with an `Intent` that identifies your `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service`, and put that `PendingIntent` in an extra for the `Intent` used with `startService()`
3. Your service in the other process, when it has data to deliver to the activity process, [calls `send()` on the `PendingIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#send(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)), including an `Intent` with data to fill into the broadcast or service request
4. Your `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service` from step #1 takes the `Intent` delivered to it and uses an event bus to let the rest of your activity process know about whatever happened, also handling the case where *nothing* in the activity process is registered for the event (e.g., raise a `Notification` if all activities were destroyed)

Comment: Thanks for help! Will try this out.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. Worked without any issues. Got data from service process with the help of `PendingIntent` and `BroadcastReceiver`. Used EventBus to further transfer that data to UI components.