# GreenRobot EventBus not receiving message in Background service posted by Activity

Tags: android

In my Activity I send [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new String("We are the champions"));
}
```

In my background service I register EventBus and try to get sent message from Activity like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

public void onEventBackgroundThread(String s){
        Log.d(TAG, "onEventBackgroundThread: " + s);
    }
```

But nothing happens. I tried to search internet but couldn't get answer.

Errors I get

```
No subscribers registered for event class java.lang.String
No subscribers registered for event class de.greenrobot.event.NoSubscriberEvent
```

**1.Edit**

I already have EventBus communication from Service to Activity. But now I want to have it also to work in reverse direction(From Activity to Service). So is it possible that it conflicts?

Comment: It actually works in both directions when I start service with startService(Intent); in one of app Activities. But if I try to use new thread for background service it can't make communication.

Comment: Yes, I eventually got it to work by using `startService`. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "thread in background service", but I started threads in the background service that I created and I was able to accomplish my task using the `EventBus`.

Comment: I tried to  search my old code, but couldn't find the reason I couldn't communicate with background service. But as far as I remember it was something related to threads.

Comment: Answer for background service is mentioned [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431768/how-to-send-event-from-service-to-activity-with-otto-event-bus

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define a custom message event class:

```
public class MyMessageEvent {
   String s;
}
```

Then you should add a subscriber method into your service. Key thing is to include your `MyMessageEvent` as the parameter:

```
public void onEventBackgroundThread(MyMeasageEvent  myEvent){
        Log.d(TAG, "onEventBackgroundThread: " + myEvent.s);
    }
```

Plus make sure your service registers with `EventBus`.

Finally, create a `MyMessageEvent` in your activity and post it on the eventbus:

```
MyMessageEvent myEvent = new MyMessageEvent() ;
myEvent.s = "hello" ;

EventBus.getDefault().post(myEvent) ;
```

If it still doesn't get received, try splitting the post onto a seperate line from the get default.  Sometimes chaining doesn't work.

Comment: you saved me, it just just the chaining...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have not used greenrobot before but I think it should be similar to guava's eventbus. I think you should create an event class instead of using String. You can have a look at https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus.
e.g.

```
public class MessageEvent {
String s;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but still receive similar error